# Getting huge random numbers error while trying to get the maximum element in array - C++ error

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a program in which
the program takes 3 numbers as input: "l", "r" and "a".
I get all the values of "x" between l and r, (l and r inclusive).
example, l = 1, r = 3, x values are 1, 2, 3. so now I have a function, f(n) = ((x/a) + (x % a)),(note: [x/a] is rounded down to an integer). so I have implemented this in c++ and my code is below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    int l; 
    int r; 
    int a; 
    cin>>l>>r>>a; 
    int nums[(r-l)+2]; 
    int answers[(r-l)+2]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < (r-l)+2; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = i; 
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])-1; i++)
    {
        answers[i] = ((nums[i]/a) + (nums[i] % a)); 
    }
    int j = 0; 
    j = answers[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(answers); i++)
    {
       if (j < answers[i])
       {
            j = answers[i];
        }
   }
    cout<<j; 
}
```

but whenever I run this code, I get huge random numbers like 230984084 and all.So please point out what's wrong with my Code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Note, that this isn't valid c++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of arrays, can make things convinient.

Comment: Also at `j = answers[0];` - `answers[0]` is never assigned a value.

Comment: Also, not sure why you need to store values in `num`, why not just have a loop that runs from l to r.

Comment: You might ask yourself why one time `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])-1` and one time `sizeof(answers)` is used. Check [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: sorry, I just started learning c++ a few days ago. Thanks for the tips and help guys

Comment: @LeviIsrael The point is that one of the successes of C++ is that it started from C, but it moved on quite a bit and the code in your question is still mostly C-code. Here is an example how it could be handled in C++ with more knowledge needed but less chance for errors: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdadf81f488bf44f

Comment: And use `at()` instead of `[]` with `vector`.

Comment: Okay @stefaanv, would you mind posting your comment as an answer, so that i can mark it as an answer and everyone knows it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request from Levi to post my comment as answer:

The point is that one of the successes of C++ is that it started from C, but it moved on quite a bit and the code in your question is still mostly C-code. Here is an example how it could be handled in C++ with more knowledge needed but less chance for errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Give 'left', 'right' and 'process' values: \n";
    int l, r, a; 
    std::cin >> l >> r >> a; 

    std::vector<int> nums((r-l)+2); 
    std::vector<int> answers; 
    // fill container with ascending numbers
    std::iota(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 1);
    // transform as needed
    std::transform(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::back_inserter(answers), [a](int i) { return i/a + i%a; });
    // find maximum element in container (returns iterator to element)
    auto maxv = std::max_element(answers.begin(), answers.end()); 
    std::cout << *maxv; 
}
```

Comment: okay thanks, but 1 doubt, can I just use #include<bits/stdc++.h> instead of the first five  lines?

Comment: @LeviIsrael technically, you can use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` but it is not the best habit when you start making larger programs and you want to be more explicit about dependencies.